# Changing the user and directory in Apache

Tags: apache-httpd

So, I'm trying to change the default user and default doc directory in apache on my PI. I've successfully changed the user and group in the /etc/apche2/envvars file, and with that change everything seems to still be fine. The user is a member of the www-data group if that helps. I've then created a new folder in the home/user/ directory, and pointed the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf file at it. I've put an index.html file in the directory, but when I attempt to browse to the PI, I get a forbidden error. Anyone know what I'm missing? This is the output of `ls -l`:

`chadianscot@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l
total 1488
drwxr-xr-x 2 chadianscot chadianscot    4096 Mar 11 12:01 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 root        root           4096 Mar 11 11:15 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 2 chadianscot chadianscot    4096 Mar 11 12:01 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 2 chadianscot chadianscot    4096 Mar 14 15:14 htmldocs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root        1480310 Mar  3  2015 logmein-hamachi_2.1.0.139-1_armhf.deb
drwxr-xr-x 2 chadianscot chadianscot    4096 Mar 11 12:01 Music
drwxr-xr-x 2 chadianscot chadianscot    4096 Mar 11 12:01 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 root        root           4096 Mar 11 15:57 Programs
drwxr-xr-x 2 chadianscot chadianscot    4096 Mar 11 12:01 Public
drwxr-xr-x 2 chadianscot chadianscot    4096 Mar 11 12:01 Templates
drwxr-xr-x 2 chadianscot chadianscot    4096 Mar 11 12:01 Videos`

The index.html file has the same permissions as the htmldocs folder.

Comment: I would guess it is going to be something to do with parent folder permissions.  Might get more luck on super user or stack exchange.  Paste some more info eg ls -la outputs etc.